# Call a function on a other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, call

I have made a lot of functions. I put these functions in a script.js file. But all these functions are loading on every page.

I have made the functions like this:

```
$(function () {
}):
```

But how can I ensure that the functions are not loading on every page? 
That I can call only the function that I need?

Comment: Give the function a name, and then make sure you are calling the function on a specific event, say on a button click, page load etc.

Comment: You need to define function out of the scope for certain pages or use condition to either load functions or not ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul Irish has a nice way of dealing with that problem. See his article:

- [Automate firing of onload events](http://paulirish.com/2008/automate-firing-of-onload-events/)

You can basically create an structure for each of your pages like this:

```
var siteNameSpace  = {
   homepage : {
      onload : function(){
         // do this stuff.
      }
   },
   contact : {
      onload : function(){
         // onload stuff for contact us page
      }
    }
};
```

And respective page's code will fire only with:

```
$(document).ready( siteNameSpace[ document.body.id ].onload );
```

For that, you need to assign an `id` to `body` tag of each of your pages:

```
<body id="home">
<body id="contactUs">
and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to split the `.js` files into modules, and only include the `.js` files that are relevant to the page.

In jQuery, it is perhaps more common to use an approach such as this:

```
$(function () {

    if (someCheck) {
        // do something
    }

    if (someCheck) {
        // do something else
    }

});
```

The `someChecks` are usually checking that a specific element exists (`if ($(someSelector).length)`).

However, to specifically answer your question, you'd give the functions a name and then call them, so instead of having;

```
$(function () {
  // do foo
})
```

You'd have

```
function someName() {
  // do foo
}
```

and then you can call the function like `someName()`, but obviously you'd need to put the function call in a place which you could control on  per-page basis (such as in the `<head>` of the page, or by including different `.js` files as explained earlier in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create few sets of external javascript files, place them in page wherever they are required.

Alternatively you can load script using jQuery's [`getScript` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript);

```
$.getScript('url of ext js', function(data, textStatus) { 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand what you're exactly asking for, but maybe I can clear some things out for you.
It doesn't matter if variables (functions) are declared in different files, what does matter is in what **scope** they are declared.
In other words, even if the functions are in different files, if they're declared global (not inside a closure/function/object), they are visible and can be called from anywhere.
Ex of global functions:

```
function foo() {/*...*/}
var bar = function(){/*...*/}
window.func = function(){/*...*/}
```

If you want to "*hide*" the functions, making them inaccessible from a different scope, you should use a closure.
Ex of functions defined in closure:

```
function initialise {
   var foo = function(){}
   function bar(){}
   alert(typeof foo); // function
   alert(typeof bar); // function
   // foo & bar are visiblehere
}
alert(typeof foo); // undefined
alert(typeof bar); // undefined
// foo & bar are undefined here
```

More over, if you want to execute them only once and completely make them inaccessible, you can wrap them in a self executing function :

```
(function(){
    function bar(){}
    alert(typeof bar);// function
    // bar is visible here
})();
// bar is undefined here
```

I don't know if I answered your question, but I hope info this helps.